# PDO update multiple rows in a single function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this function that I am trying to have execute multiple update statements, but it keeps throwing this error but it only executes the first query if though both $this->status_name and $this->status_state are greater than 1.

```
function update(){
        if (strlen($this->status_name)>1) {
           // update query
            $query = "UPDATE
                        " . $this->table_name . "
                    SET
                        status_name = :status_name
                    WHERE
                        status_id = :status_id";
          
            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
          
            // sanitize
            $this->status_name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->status_name));
          
            // bind new values
            $stmt->bindParam(':status_name', $this->status_name);
            $stmt->bindParam(':status_id', $this->status_id);
          
            // execute the query
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return true;
            }
          
            return false;
        }

        if (strlen($this->status_state)>1) {
           // update query
            $query = "UPDATE
                        " . $this->table_name . "
                    SET
                        status_state = :status_state
                    WHERE
                        status_id = :status_id";
          
            // prepare query statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
          
            // sanitize
            $this->status_state=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->status_state));
          
            // bind new values
            $stmt->bindParam(':status_state', $this->status_state);
            $stmt->bindParam(':status_id', $this->status_id);
          
            // execute the query
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return true;
            }
          
            return false;
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve successfully running multiple satements in a single function using PDO?

Comment: `...number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` in the error message is because in both of the queries, you only bind 1 parameter, but nothing is provided for the `id` portion, so there should be 2 values for both update queries.

Comment: @PaulT. My bad. Thanks for the heads up. But unfortunately it keeps executing the first statement only. Nothing happens to the subsequent statements

Comment: Right, and for that part is because you have a `return` within the first `if` block which will immediately exit the function ... there's no way to continue without reconsidering the handling flow. As a basic test, you could commment-out the returns to check a run. Seems that you could possibly update both columns with one query, but I don't know the expected handling.